# Get notified about process termination

Tags: linux, ipc

I’m trying to use NETLINK with CN_IDX_PROC to monitor my process. This works but requires the monitoring process to be launched with root privileges.

I’ve tried to fix it by setting a capability in the filesystem on my monitoring executable (including CAP_AUDIT_READ, CAP_SYS_ADMIN,CAP_SYS_PTRACE and CAP_IPC_OWNER), but it didn’t work, bind() still fails saying “Operation not permitted” unless using `sudo` to start.

Is there a way to enable non-roots to use netlink connector sockets the way I want?

If no, is there any other reliable way to get notified when other (non child, running under different user account) process terminates? I don’t want to poll: it’s embedded software, I don’t have much resources, and I want to get notified ASAP. I especially want to get notified if the target process terminates abnormally, e.g. with segmentation fault, so I can’t rely on target process being cooperative.

On Windows I’d just create & lock a named mutex in the target process, and make the monitor process to sleep on it, mutexes are guaranteed to be released as soon as the owner process dies. Is there a similar IPC mechanism in Linux?

Comment: Can't you use [waitpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) or similar?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Can't. All of these system calls are used to wait for state changes `in a child of the calling process`

Comment: You could wrap your process in some other one (which just `fork`-s and `waitpid`-s)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Could you please be more specific? Both processes are mine, but they’re not in parent-child relations. Both are created by systemd, but they have different lifetimes, different user accounts, different environments.

Comment: @Soots: I provided an answer. But I don't have time to explain all the details (but gave links to follow)

Comment: @amdn I don't think you link answers that question: "Need sudo (CAP_SYS_ADMIN) for BPF() system call"

Comment: @Soonts, indeed! I removed my comment, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to be notified about the termination of a process, e.g. running some program `foo`.

BTW, if that process behaves well, you might use [atexit(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/atexit.3.html) inside the source code of `foo`. Then, if that program exits correctly (by calling [exit(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exit.3.html) explicitly, or by returning from `main`; the [crt0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crt0) is calling [exit(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exit.3.html) in such case just after `main` returned), the registered routine is running when you want. But that `foo` process can sadly be terminated by some [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) (e.g. a [segmentation fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault), or some external [kill(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/kill.1.html) command, etc etc...), then of course [`_exit(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/_exit.2.html) is not happening (and neither is [exit(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exit.3.html) ....).

So write a simplistic wrapper program (e.g. `wrapfoo`) which [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html)-s then [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html)-s `foo` in the child, and [waitpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) in the parent. Then your `wrapfoo` is *always* notified of the end of `foo` (including when `foo` was terminated by some signal). It behaves as if it was a specialized "shell" to run `foo` (this is just for the explanation here, `wrapfoo` is *not* really a [Unix shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell)).

<sup>(of course, you don't want the process running `wrapfoo` to be terminated itself)</sup>

Coding that `wrapfoo` program is really simple. You should expect it to be correct. And you might (carefully) use [setuid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) techniques to have them using different users (if you need that). Beware that setuid tricks are difficult and without care can open a [security hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vulnerability_(computing)).

In some cases you might merge the C source code of `wrapfoo` with the code of `foo` but most of the time you don't want to ([separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) principle). Especially if you use dangerous setuid techniques, you want your `wrapfoo.c`  to be as simple as possible (and be able to prove that it works like you want it to).

Read some good book on Linux programming, e.g. download the old [Advanced Linux Programming](https://github.com/longda/free-books/blob/master/advanced-linux-programming.pdf) (also [here](http://www.cse.hcmut.edu.vn/~hungnq/courses/nap/alp.pdf); it is legally freely downloadable) or something newer. *setuid* techiques and all the subtilities behind [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html), [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html), [waitpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) ... are difficult to explain (so I won't even try here). See also [credentials(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html).

Maybe you could use a [fifo(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html), use some advisory locking (e.g. [flock(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/flock.2.html) or [lockf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/lockf.3.html)...); the kernel releases them too when a process dies.

Comment: Thanks, ended up doing just that. My initial pthread mutex-based implementation appeared to be too fragile, too many possible edge cases. This approach appears to work OK, at least so far. BTW I use a datagram unix domain socket in the wrapper, to communicate with the real owner.
Can’t merge the wrapper because the process being wrapped is Microsoft’s dotnet running my C# code, that thing is huge and I don’t want to recompile & patch.

Answer (score 0):

Implemented a workaround with named shared memory section with a pthread mutex in that.

Funfact: when the mutex is forcefully released because the owner process terminates, `pthread_mutex_lock` of the other process returns `EOWNERDEAD` code, however the mutex it’s no longer usable after that, subsequent pthread_mutex_lock on that mutex return 131 = EOTHER error code. Fortunately I’m only synchronizing 2 processes, so I’m OK just recreating the mutex in the same shared memory section.

Surprising amount of code to replicate a single WaitForSingleObject Win32 API :-(